# Unable to direct Route53 records to new server

Tags: networking, dns, digital-ocean, amazon-route53

I am trying to point a domain from a website (radicalxchange.org) currently hosted by Firebase to a new version hosted in a Digital Ocean droplet. The name servers are managed by AWS Route53. When I change the A record in Route53 to my D.O. droplet IP address (167.99.59.52), the site immediately stops loading. I've tried to wait a few hours but it never connects.

I should note that Route53 contains a lot of other stuff related to our site (CNAME, MX & TXT records) however I've been under the impression that the only thing necessary to route website traffic to the new IP is the A record. What am I doing wrong?

[image: n]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your Digital Ocean droplet is kind of misconfigured:

1) from current hosting, you have permanent redirect to `https` (and if your browser have that already cached, it will immediately go to `https://radicalxchange.org`), and you don't have `https` configured in your new hosting

2)  Even if you use clean browser, your new `http://radicalxchange.org` will redirect you to http://167.99.59.52/, which is quite strange.

[image]

I suggest you hardcode `167.99.59.52 radicalxchange.org` entry in your [hosts file](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/), and test thoroughly, and only then make DNS changes.

Comment: Thanks that definitely helped. I just needed to add TLS/SSL